# How nonanalytic can a function be while being infinitely differentiable everywhere?

Tags: real-analysis, analyticity

Let us assign to the function $g:x\mapsto\exp(-1/x^2)$ the value $0$ at $x=0$, so that it is in $\mathrm C^\infty(\Bbb R)$; namely it is infinitely differentiable everywhere in $\Bbb R$. It is well known that $g$ is nonanalytic at $0$, although analytic everywhere else. Now let $(r_n:n\in \Bbb N)$ be an enumeration of a countable dense subset $D$ of $\Bbb R$ (e.g. $D=\Bbb Q)$. Then $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ defined by $$f(x)=\sum_{n\in \Bbb N}\frac1{2^n}g(x-r_n)$$is nonanalytic at any point in $D$. **Edit:** Moreover, as pointed out by @MartinR, it is nonanalytic everywhere, and it is not true, as claimed in the original question, that “... it is analytic everywhere in $\Bbb R\setminus D$ ”. Consequently the question below is answered affirmatively by the example already given above.

Can a function in $\mathrm C^\infty(\Bbb R)$ be nonanalytic on an uncountable set?

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, your $f$ is nowhere analytic, because any power series has a positive radius of convergence, i.e. the  set where $f$ is analytic is open.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-analytic_smooth_function#A_smooth_function_which_is_nowhere_real_analytic

Comment: @MartinR: Of course you are right! I will edit.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fabius_function

Comment: Why do you think your $f$ satisfies the last question?

Comment: @zhw.: Because $D$ is dense. If $f$ were analytic somewhere—say at a point $a$, with a positive radius of convergence $r$—then it would be analytic everywhere within the open interval between $a-r$ and $a+r$. But this interval contains a point of $D$ (since $D$ is dense), yielding a contradiction.

Comment: But why do you think $f$ is $C^\infty?$

Comment: @zhw: Because, for each $m\in\Bbb N$,the $m$th derivative $g^{(m)}$ is bounded. Hence, for each $x\in\Bbb R$, all the shifted terms $g^{(m)}(x-r_n)\,$ ($n\in\Bbb N$) are restricted by the same bounds. This ensures the convergence of the infinite series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty2^{-n} g^{(m)}(x-r_n)$.

Comment: Ah thank you, that was easy.